# Why you cannot `git pull SHA...650839#file-diff.pach`?

Tags: git, github

I want to download a portion of this diff: https://gist.github.com/sergeykish/650839#file-dvorak-de-diff. Pseudocode

```
git pull https://gist.github.com/sergeykish/650839#file-dvorak-de-diff.patch
```

Comment: You should download the file then apply patch.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Download the file or the patch? `git` url does not support anchors (the part behind #) address part of diff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git pull` is used for updating existing repository. If you want to download the content of the new repository, there is `git clone` command:

```
 $ git clone https://gist.github.com/sergeykish/650839
Cloning into '650839'...
remote: Counting objects: 15, done.
remote: Total 15 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 15
Unpacking objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
 $ cd 650839/
 650839 (master)$ ls
dvorak-de.diff  winkeys-ua.diff
 650839 (master)$ cat dvorak-de.diff
```

You can download the single diff by clicking to the button <kbd>Raw</kbd> on the linked page. Or copy the url and from shell:

```
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sergeykish/650839/raw/ce43a3b70e769b6de8ecf996298455bc0f622125/dvorak-de.diff
```

Comment: I added instructions to download of the single `diff` to the answer,